# how to fetch sent sms details through broadcast receiver

Tags: android

** android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT not working **

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        initObjects(context);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED)) {

            // message detail  fetching
            getAllSms(context);
            // initializeList();
        }else
            if(intent.getAction().equals(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT) ){
                getAllSms(context);

            } else{

                Toast.makeText(context, "this intent filter action is not working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your OnResume call back

```
sentStatusReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            String s = "Unknown Error";
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    s = "Message Sent Successfully !!";
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    s = "Generic Failure Error";
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    s = "Error : No Service Available";
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    s = "Error : Null PDU";
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    s = "Error : Radio is off";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            sendStatusTextView.setText(s);

        }
    };
```

> Here's code for sms detail

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), 
 null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // must check the result to prevent exception
    do {
       String msgData = "";
       for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
       {
           msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
       }
       // use msgData
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
} else {
   // empty box, no SMS
}
```